# How to label columns by reading in from a file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My real issue is that I cant seem to use the header names after I use them but I think its caused by labeling the headers wrong.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

dataFrame1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/data/data/featurenames.txt', header=None, encoding='utf-8')


dataFrame2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/data/data/DataSet.txt')

dataFrame2.columns=[dataFrame1]
```

The result is the following:

If I use `print (dataFrame2)`

I get this result [The headers are in brackets for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhbMZ.png)
`
[image]

But if I use `print (dataFrame2['id'])`

I get -  **KeyError: 'id'**

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It looks like your column name is not `'id'`, but `'(id,)'`.  Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at dataFrame2.columns there will be correct column names.
You could use

```
dataFrame2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/data/data/DataSet.txt',header=None,names=dataFrame1)
```